# zend: storing sessions in a database when using multidb

Tags: php, zend-framework

my zend application uses multiple database connections, so i used the `multidb` resource to configure several connections in the `application.ini` file.

now i want to store the application sessions into the database, using `Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable`, but i can't find a way to specify which of those connections to use in order to access the database.

every examples i found on the net uses the `db` resource and relies on the default database adapter. unfortunately, the sessions have to be stored in a database which is not the default one...

how do i specify which db to use for storing session ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

although it is not specified in the Zend documentation, the constructor for the `Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable` class accepts a parameter named `db` which specifies the database connection to use.

```
$db = $this->getPluginResource('multidb')->getDb('zend');
$config = array(
    'db'             => $db,
    'name'           => 'session',
    'primary'        => 'id',
    'modifiedColumn' => 'modified',
    'dataColumn'     => 'data',
    'lifetimeColumn' => 'lifetime'
);
Zend_Session::setSaveHandler(new Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable($config));
Zend_Session::start();
```

i was not able to specfy those settings in the `application.ini`configuration file, though...

Comment: what is this then http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.savehandler.dbtable.html ?

Comment: @Venu: can you please show me where, on this documentation page, it is explicitly written that the key should be named `'db'` and the value is the connection object ?  (there is an obscure comment: `//or you can pass the db connection straight to the save handler` which does not tell how to achieve this)

Comment: Apologies for that! Yes, I agree it was not clear though, but they have mentioned it.

Comment: anyway here is my +1 for you for answering your question :)